# Is it possible to not use styles.css for a specific div or tag, but instead use tailwind css?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, tailwind-css

I basically want to stop a div or a button from being influenced by my styles.css, since I want to only use tailwind css for that tag. Basically I want something like below, if it is possible:

```
<button class="stop-being-influenced-by-styles.css flex border-0...other tailwind css">Button</button>
```

Thank you, and please leave any comments if you have a question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your tailwind link tag comes after your style.css tag and you should check if you have `!important` properties that affects your button tag. Your import should look like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwindcss">`